# Android white labeling

Tags: android, apk, white-labelling

I am working for a company which has this "foo" app on the store, the app is a helper for our hardware which is revelled by resellers. We made sure that the name is as generic as possible - in order for our vendors to be able to market the app as "their app".

However - some re-sellers do want to have their exact name and icon on the app. And they are willing to pay so, I need to make this happen.

Questions:

1. I understand that I am looking for build variants. But still, how can I modify the apk-package-name , display name is default launcher icon using build variants?
2. Is this permitted...? I am not "officially" spamming the store, but it feels like I could get banned for doing that exactly.
3. Code signing - I will upload the APK my self, and I will need to sign using different certificates (whatever it's called on android). Again - this is vague, and I cannot find documentation on this subject.
4. I also plan on releasing a beta version of my app in this way. I am currently using the  standard mechanism, but this means that testers cannot show case the app to customers (as it's not finished or crashing most of the time) [1]
5. Does the term "white labeling" apply here...?

[1] the joys of working in a small company :)

Comment: For #2-  a small number isn't uncommon, you'll see free and paid versions of a lot of apps.  As for #3-  would you guys really be uploading it for them?  I would think you'd deliver them an apk for acceptance testing and they would upload it themselves.  I wouldn't want my company's name out on something I didn't approve.

Comment: @GabeSechan you are a technical person so you got the problem. I was thinking similarly - what happen if foolab company asks me to build a build flavor and in 3 year they say "ok, now I go with my own code - give me the certificate to sign against"? When I asked that I was told that "foolab" usually are extremely non technical and will not even understand what I ask.

Comment: I used to work at a small company where we had to do something similar. You'll probably want to automate the whole process, including uploading to google play, (but ofc excluding signing). The other approach quickly becomes very expensive and makes it way too easy to forget one of the whitelabled apps when updating. As we did, more than once.. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with build variants as you suspected but also you would likely need Flavors.

Here is an example gradle file that has multiple build types and flavors. You set the ApplicationId (packagename used in Play Store) in the flavor settings.

Set up the signing in each type/flavor. You can add resources, icons, manifests etc that are specific to each flavor. You can even replace whole class files so customer specific code is only included in the apk for the customer you are building for.

```
  defaultConfig {
    applicationId "uk.co.foo.default"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode = 113
    versionName = "3.2.3"
}

signingConfigs {
    release {
        storeFile file("X:\\Android Projects\\Keystore\\MyKeys.jks")
        storePassword "MyPassword"
        keyAlias "KeyAlias"
        keyPassword "itsasecret"
    }
}

productFlavors {
    Customer1 {
        applicationId "uk.co.foo.customer1"
    }

    Customer2 {
        applicationId "uk.co.foo.customer2"
    }
}

buildTypes {

    debug {
        applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
        versionNameSuffix " Debug"
    }

    beta {
        applicationIdSuffix ".beta"
        versionNameSuffix " Beta"
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }

    signed {
        minifyEnabled false
        debuggable true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }

    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}
```

Here is the folder structure for adding resources for each type\flavor. In this example, the second flavor is called "fan". The "main" folder is used by default. Each type and flavors resources are merged into the apk (replacing any of the same name in the main folder) depending on which build you choose in the "Build Variants" section of Android Studio.

[image]

Android Studio will display which folders are in effect for the current build as shown highlighted in this image.

[image]

---

Edit - full official documentation is available here: https://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html

Comment: OK, this with the upstream documentation (I edited your response to contain the correct link) clarifies a lot. Nice touch using `storeFile file` and related keys. That helps a lot. Still does not answers "will I get kicked out of the play store" - but this is not something you can answer.

Comment: Google are quite up front about their policies so you should find what you need here: https://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy.html

Comment: New question - I did that, I got my apps working... now when I choose to generate a signed package from AndroidStudio - it asks me for a keystore path, instead of using the one in the gradle file. Which means - I can (and did) sign a package with the wrong keystore. Besides "thinking twice" and "using gradle  from the command line" - what is the best way to avoid this problem?

Comment: Shall I use different keys for different white-labelled apps? I am using a single key for all white-labelled. But it shows the weak key one of the new push. Shall I need to update or it needs to create a new key. If I create a new one does it affect the existing apps?